# ASP.Net MVC: Handle database related errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I'm using Dapper ORM to query the Sql server database in my ASP.Net MVC application.

for e.g.

```
public class Product
{
 int ProductId;
 string ProductName;
}
public IDbConnection  myDb = new SqlConnection(myConnString);

myQuery = "Select * from Product";
```

I've following line in my various controllers:

```
myDb.Query<Product>(myQuery, Product).Single();
```

I need to be able to log the database related runtime errors(for e.g. db not reachable, db is shutdown, permissions error, etc.) and then redirect to a custom error page.

Should I be handling this in the Application_error in using Global.asax.cs file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are various ways you could achieve that, but I think you could define global error handler, check the type (or namespace?) of exception, if it was related to database, and take appropriate action. [Here you can find starting point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)